# Keep a column in sync with another column in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a column always *kept in sync* with another column in the same table.

Let this table be an example:

```
+------+-----------+
| name | name_copy |
+------+-----------+
| John | John      |
+------+-----------+
| Mary | Mary      |
+------+-----------+
```

I'd like to:

Be able to `INSERT` into this table, providing a value only for the `name` column - The `name_copy` column should automatically take the value I used in `name`

When `UPDATE`-ing the `name` column on a pre-existing row, the `name_copy` should automatically update to match the new & updated `name_column`.

#### Some solutions

- I could do this via code but that would be terribly bad as there's no guarantee the data would always be accessible by my code (what if someone changes the data through a DB client?)

Comment: What is the reason for this request?

Comment: @TheGameiswar Audit Trail mechanism - The `printName` stores the actual human-readable name of the row so it can be picked up by the mechanism instead of picking up the PK - It's a bit complicated to explain here

Comment: Why not selecting the same column twice? `select name,name as name_copy from t`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Computed column`

> A computed column is a virtual column that is not physically stored in
>   the table, unless the column is marked PERSISTED. A computed column
>   expression can use data from other columns to calculate a value for
>   the column to which it belongs

```
Alter table tablename add name_copy as (name) persisted
```

If the column already exists then you need to drop and recreate the column

```
Alter table tablename DROP COLUMN name_copy

Alter table tablename add name_copy as (name) persisted
```

Instead of dropping, you can rename the old column and add the new computed column. Check if everything is fine then drop the renamed column. To rename use the below code

```
EXEC sp_rename 'tablename.name_copy', 'bckup_name_copy', 'COLUMN';
```

Comment: Is there any way to designate the `name_copy` as the computed column if `name_copy` already exists?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides - You need to drop and recreate

Answer (score 3):

This is an odd request, but you can do it with a computed column:

```
alter table t add name_copy as (name);
```

`name_copy` is not actually stored in the table (unless you explicitly materialize it).  It is kept up-to-date when queried.